# How to use a MOBAC created atlas with OpenLayers for an offline map?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I've been using MOBAC to create atlas' for OSMDroid on Android devices, but I was interested in seeing if I can create a matching view of those tiles from a Web app. This is where I started looking at the obvious Javascript mapping API choice, Openlayers.

Openlayers has examples for offline caching of tiles but I need to get it to load my tiles in the first place. OpenStreetMaps has some good samples on using your own tiles locally as well.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Local_Tiles_Example

In my test code, which is all hosted by a Web server, I have a tile directory structure like so:

```
./tiles/<zoom>/<x>/<y.png>
```

Which is basically the OpenStreetMaps map format. When I try using the below sample I'll see a request from Chrome to my Web server for `http://127.0.0.1/tiles/0/0/0.png` which is naturally not going to exist.

I guess my question is, how are projections, boundaries and map centering (long/lat) used with OpenLayers? I realize that Geo mapping is complicated, but the point of using an API like this is to simply the headaches around embedded maps. I simply want to display my map tile set and define the long/lat and zoom levels.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <title>Map Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./theme/default/style.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"> -->
    <script src="./OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map, layer;

        var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); // Canada
        var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); // Canada

        function init(){
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('test_map');
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
                "Local Tiles",
                "tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png");
            map.addLayer(layer);
            map.setCenter(
                new OpenLayers.LonLat(-76.885610, 42.345822).transform(fromProjection,toProjection), 19);
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <h1 id="title">Map Example</h1>
    <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I know what's going on now. I made some assumptions based on my experiment with OSMDroid for Android.

First, a typo. OpenLayer.Map() should be constructed with the div ID where the map is supposed to be inserted.

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('test_map');
```

Should be:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
```

Because of:

```
<div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
```

Second, the Openlayers zoom level appear to be unforgiving, and a bit strange. If you programmatically zoom to a level beyond the supported resolution, you'll appear in no mans land. A zoom level of 19 won't display anything, a zoom level of 18 will. I have a tile set that goes all the way to 20, so I'll need to sort out how to define layer resolution scale correctly, but that's for another post.